# Why does Hibernate allow me to insert a null value on a foreign key constraint?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

I am experimenting with jpa and hibernate relations. I'm using a table named users and a table named emails. A user can have many emails.

When I run my Spring boot application along with the following code I get one email record in my h2 database. The email_address of this record is testAddress and the user_username column of this record is null. The user_username column is listed as a foreign key on the emails table. My question is, why is emailRepository.save(email1) successful when there is no corresponding user in the database?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emails")
public class Email {

    @Id
    private String emailAddress;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    ...

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String username;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<Email> emails;

    ...

}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

}

public interface EmailRepository extends JpaRepository<Email, String> {

}

@Component
public class UserRepositoryCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private EmailRepository emailRepository;

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Email email1 = new Email();
        email1.setEmailAddress("testAddress");
        emailRepository.save(email1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Guessing you mean the save method completed but the transaction commit fails? Or the new row is committed ok with a null for the foreign key?

Comment: The new row is committed ok with a null for the foreign key.

Comment: It shows as a FK called USER_USERNAME when I go to http://localhost:8080/h2-console/   -> EMAILS -> Indexes ->FK... with property non unique. I'm assuming that means I have a foreign key relation to the users table.

Comment: If I set the user id="testUser" to the email with id="testAddress" and save that email, then the application does complain that testUser cannot be found. So that is good. I'm not sure if I can add a not null constraint to something which already has a relationship annotation. I don't think it should let me add a null value anyway though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation of the JoinColumn annotation:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#nullable()

It is mentioned:

> If the JoinColumn annotation itself is defaulted, a single join column
>   is assumed and the default values apply.

Since you did not specify a `JoinColumn` in your `ManyToOne` mapping, then Hibernate would assume the default `JoinColumn`. If you take a look at the `JoinColumn.nullable` attribute, it is defaulted to true. Thus, when Hibernate generates your schema, the foreign key column is by default NULLABLE.

You may need to explicitly add a `@JoinColumn` annotation on top of your `@ManyToOne` mapping and set its `nullable` attribute to false.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable=false)
private User user;
```

This way, it'll throw out an error when you try to insert email without a user.

Comment: Actually, it might make more sense to use `@ManyToOne(optional=false)`. It will enforce consistency at the application level without even hitting the db

Comment: In my case I had a @JoinColumn and still got this behavior. Not sure why the DB (postgres) is allowing this.. edit: adding `nullable=false` to the join column annotation I already had in did not change this behavior.